# Apply "text-overflow: ellipsis;" to inner div

Tags: html, css

I have a div structure similar to following image. 
[image: image 1]

I need to apply "text-overflow: ellipsis;" to text in this div structure in smaller windows.(image 2)

[image: image 2]

But it didn't apply as I expect. this is my HTML code

```css
    .header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .header > .header_middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .header > .header_middle.share-file-header > .caption {
  float: left !important;
  line-height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 30px;
 }
 .header > .header_middle.share-file-header .settings {
  line-height: inherit;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
  float: right;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
 }
 .shared-person-detail-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: inherit;
 }
 .settings .share-files-msg, .settings .shared-person {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
 .settings .more-persons-wraper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
    <div class="header_middle share-file-header">
        <div class="caption">
            <p>
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="/resources/Image1.png" alt="Image 1" title="Image 1">
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="settings">
            <div class="shared-person-detail-wrapper">
                <div class="shared-person">
                    User Name <a href="mailto:user@email.com">(user@email.com)</a>
                </div>
                <div class="share-files-msg">
                    has shared file(s) with you
                    <div class="more-persons-wraper">and some <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="more">more</a> people.
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="more-persons">
                            <li>user1@email.com</li>
      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="share-icon"><img src="/resources/Image2.png" alt="Image 2" title="Image 2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the wrong with this code, can any one give me a guide ?? thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for an element to have overflow as elipsis you  need to set these CSS rules on it:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 60px; #(any width would do)
```

Here is a jsfiddle where I have added these on the .shared-person class.
https://jsfiddle.net/3dukmv5q/