# How to apply text-overflow: ellipsis and overflow: unset together

Tags: html, css

How can I handle the css that I need to set up `overflow: unset` to let me poptip display when hovering and also display `ellipsis` once data in cell is oversize?
I have following HTML under my table. In order to make sure `div` element pop up a warning message that does not cover by `td` element when hovering on `span` element. I have to set `overflow: unset` on `td` level.
After setting that up, it seems like `text-overflow` does not work anymore?
Suggestion?
I check some posts and all mentioned about `overflow: hidden`
so i am wondering if any solution for me?
[Apply "text-overflow: ellipsis;" to inner div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140756/apply-text-overflow-ellipsis-to-inner-div)
and
[List Overflow; Do text-overflow: ellipsis;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260502/list-overflow-do-text-overflow-ellipsis)

**My code:**

```css
.tr .td {
    position: sticky
    overflow: unset;
    z-index: 2;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="td" role="cell" style="position: sticky; left: 46px;">
     <span class="data" aria-expanded="false">
        cell data
        <div class="poptip" role="tooltip" aria-hidden="true"></div>
     </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell?

Comment: yap...but my problem is I have to set `overflow: unset` here